# Matching all Characters between two Strings using Sed or any Unix command

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a log file and i want to delete all com.test.data text in my log file.In example below I want all occurrences in bold to be striped out.

The new lines after the text I want are causing havoc, removing all \n would ruin the entire.log file.

I have tried `grep -e 'com.test.data' debug.log --color -v > test.log`.

Also tried `sed 's/com.test.data -\(.*\)2016-01/\1/' debug.log > test.log`.

Also tried `sed '/'com.test.data -'/,/2016-01/ s/[a-z]*// p' debug.log > test.log`

All seem to fail.

My plan was find all text between 'com.test.data -' and '2016-01' replace all of this with 'empty'(delete all).
Then take my file and use grep to give me all lines except 'com.test.data -'.
 Doing this first seems to get me closer.

INPUT

```
2016-01-05 14:45:05,264 com.test.data - blah blah blahsd

afdadfasdfsd
sdsdfsdffssfddsf

dfsdsfdfsdfdsdfs
fsdsdfdfs
2016-01-05 14:46:05,264 com.test.rest - Testing 123
2016-01-05 14:47:05,264 com.test.data - blah blah blahsd

afdadfasdfsd
sdsdfsdffssfddsf
dfsdsfdfsdfdsdfs

fsdsdfdfs
2016-01-05 14:46:05,264 com.test.rest - Testing 123
```

OR USE

```
sed 's/^2016-01/@/' debug.log > test.log //Add @ to beginning of file
```

Now its just finding text from com.test.data ---> @

NEW INPUT TO MAKE THINGS EASIER

```
@-05 14:45:05,264 com.test.data - blah blah blahsd

afdadfasdfsd
sdsdfsdffssfddsf

dfsdsfdfsdfdsdfs
fsdsdfdfs
@-05 14:46:05,264 com.test.rest - Testing 123
@-05 14:47:05,264 com.test.data - blah blah blahsd

afdadfasdfsd
sdsdfsdffssfddsf
dfsdsfdfsdfdsdfs

fsdsdfdfs
@-05 14:46:05,264 com.test.rest - Testing 123
```

OUTPUT

```
2016-01-05 14:46:05,264 com.test.rest - Testing 123

2016-01-05 14:46:05,264 com.test.rest - Testing 123
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clearly post the input in its original form and how you want the output to appear.

Comment: I think I understand now, but adding an example of the desired output whould have helped tremendously.

Comment: Ok I will do that as well.

Comment: Still not super clear. How about adding a line that *should* be printed, in addition to the empty one?

Comment: So far this has been great @BenjaminW. - sed 's/^2016-01/@/' file.txt > test.log //Add @ to beginning of file. However -> aftersed '/data/,/@/d' test.log > test2.log does not work.

Comment: Now its deleting data to @ is the last part left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following script does not do exactly what you want, it should be very easy to adapt it to your requirements.  It is also portable, efficient, and maintainable:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {ok=1}
  /^ *@-/ { if ($3 == "com.test.data") {ok=0; next} else {ok=1} }
  ok {print}'
```

Comment: Thank so much Benjamin got really close, but this is very easy to read, and maintainable. Works like magic for real error logs That might have ERROR after I just incremented $3 to $4 to get the correct split.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
sed -r -n '/^[0-9:, -]{24}com\.test\.data /{:a;n;/^[0-9:, -]{24}/!ba;/ com\.test\.data /ba;};p;' file
```

In some unix systems, the option `-r` doesn't exist and is replaced by `-E` *(to use the extended regular expression syntax)*

Comment: This cannot run. sed -r -n '/^[0-9:, -]{24}com\.test\.data /{:a;n;/^[0-9:, -]{24}/!ba;/ com\.test\.data /ba;};p' file.txt
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: @Thefirstkilla This means you probably don't have GNU grep. You can still use this without the `-r`, but you have to replace the two occurences of `{24}` with `\{24\}`.

Comment: hmmph i havegrep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD @BenjaminW.

Comment: @Thefirstkilla So, does `sed -n '/^[0-9:, -]\{24\}com\.test\.data /{:a;n;/^[0-9:, -]\{24\}/!ba;/ com\.test\.data /ba;};p' file` work or not?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Nope. sed: 1: "/^[0-9:, -]\{24\}com\.t ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: @Thefirstkilla: use the original answer, but replace `-r` with `-E`

Answer (score 1):

This script loops through the input and remembers if the last line that started with a date contained `com.test.data` or not. If it didn't, the line gets printed.

```
#!/bin/bash

re='^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'

printflag=1

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line]]; do
    if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
        if [[ $line =~ com\.test.\data ]]; then
            printflag=0
        else
            printflag=1
        fi
    fi
    if (( printflag )); then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

This takes the name of the logfile as parameter. When stored as `script`, use it like

```
./script debug.log
```

Comment: VERY CLOSE, but there should be two com.test.rest lines+++++++++++./stackoverflow.sh file.txt OUTPUT->
2016-01-05 14:46:05,264 com.test.rest - Testing 123

Comment: @Thefirstkilla This can happen when the input file isn't terminated with a newline. I've added a statement so it'll work also then.

Answer (score 0):

Prints lines with Testing 123

```
awk '/Testing 123/' file
2016-01-05 14:46:05,264 com.test.rest - Testing 123
2016-01-05 14:46:05,264 com.test.rest - Testing 123
```

Comment: I think OP wants all the lines between timestamped lines as well, unless the line with the timestamp contains `com.test.data`. The example shown is a little unclear because it only adds an empty line, though.